# Cyclic writings on the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've to do cyclic writings on the same file in nodejs.
In particular this is the pseudo-code:

```
value = 77;
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
if(list[i] > 10){
    proxy.setNewState(value, function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

The function "setNewState" do some nested operations:
(1) write in a file "out.txt" something...
(2) run a module that using that file to produce an URL to do an HTTP request to a server (NB: I need to write a file because this the module runs some shell commands where this file is used).
(3) return the response using the callback.

My problem (I think) is that the "for" cycle is not good because the file is re-write and so the HTTPs are not correctly executed.

Any helps? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file before your loop and write to it incrementally inside the loop. Then close it after the loop.

Assuming you are using [the standard Node File System API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html):

- Use [`fs.open()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) to asynchronously open a file or [`fs.openSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_opensync_path_flags_mode) to synchronously open a file
- Use [`fs.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) to asynchronously write to a file or [`fs.writeSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position) to synchronously write to a file. If you are using a buffer, be sure to use the method signature that takes a buffer. If you are using data, then be sure to use the method signature that takes data. Also note the warning in the docs about using the asynchronous version multiple times without waiting for the callback! If you need to do that, use [`fs.createWriteStream()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) etc. rather than these functions. That will return [a Writable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) so read the documentation for that instead/in addition.
- Use [`fs.close()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback) or [`fs.closeSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_closesync_fd) to close the file.

What you **can't** use is [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) or [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options) because those will replace the file on each write.

Comment: I'm trying to use the fs.open() and fs.write() but seems that nothing change... What I'd like to do is not to write a file "incrementally" but something like this: Cycle 1, create the file, use it to generate a http request, call the request and go with the next cycle... end so on... 
Maybe is not that cycle a good choice? Any suggestion please?